# How can I add a 'change' event listener for a styled select?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, html-select, dispatchevent

Obviously, if I have a 'select' element, I can add an event listener for changes using some basic JS:

```
document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change', function(ev){
  console.log('Changed', ev.target.value)
})
```

Click the 'select' element, modify the value, the log fires. Simple stuff.

However I'm working on a library for styled select boxes - like *chosen* or *select2* without the jQuery dependency.

In my library, clicking the styled select box changes the `.value` of the real select box:

```
query('select').value = newValue;
```

I can see this is working if I make the real select box visible.

However, changing the `value` of the select box through JS doesn't trigger the `select` boxes 'change' event.

**Is there a way I can change the select boxes value though JS and still have `change` events attached to the select box fire?**

Comment: Trying to reproduce yours I get: `TypeError: Argument 1 of EventTarget.dispatchEvent is not an object.` Try: `realSelect.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);` (without name argument);

Comment: @MartinErnst You're right, I've changed my code alternatively (and moved it to a separate answer so people actually see it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Javascript**

```
function fireEvent(element, event) {
    if (document.createEventObject) {
        // dispatch for IE
        var evt = document.createEventObject();
        return element.fireEvent('on' + event, evt)
    } else {
        // dispatch for firefox + others
        var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        evt.initEvent(event, true, true); // event type,bubbling,cancelable
        return !element.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
}

document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change', function (ev) {
    console.log('Changed', ev.target.value)
});

btn.onclick = function () {
    select.selectedIndex = 2;
    var obj = document.querySelector('select');
    fireEvent(obj, 'change');
}
```

User call

```
var yourPlugin=new CustomSelect(options);
yourPlugin.value("3");
```

Plugin function

```
function value(val) {
    if (!val) return select.value;
    select.value = val;
    fireEvent(select, 'change');
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/mkctp8ut/)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I'm looking for. I tweaked your JSFiddle a little and created http://jsfiddle.net/mkctp8ut/3/ which uses Event constructors (MDN thinks document.createEvent is out of date). Thanks for all your help!

Comment: It's really simple. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea: Trigger the event by yourself after changing the value:

```
var el = query('select');
el.value = newValue;
el.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```

Comment: That's certainly possible, but the library is intended for other people and I don't want to require that users add additional event handlers - I simply want to fire the select boxes existing handlers when the styled select is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Hamix's excellent answer, and [some advice from MDN about createEvent() being out of date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createEvent), I eventually went with:

```
var changeEvent = new Event('change');
realSelect.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);
```

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mkctp8ut/3/) - again based on @Hamix's jsfiddle so go give him an upvote.